# Is there any way to read a file besides read()?

Tags: python, file-io

Besides `read()`, `readline()` and `readlines()`, is there any other way to load the contents of a file and store it as a string?

Comment: You don't like the word `read`, huh? Why?

Comment: You don't explain enough what you want and why read is not good enough for you

Comment: `other_read_function = lambda f: f.read()`

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are odd, but here:

```
f = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
file_as_string = ''.join([line for line in f])
f.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not have  `read()`, `readline()` or `readlines()`

```
data=[]
with open('/tmp/test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:                       # equivalent to 'readline()`
        data.append(line)                # after all lines, equivalent to 'readlines()'
```

Now make it a string:

```
stofdata=''.join(data)
```